# Character count using cursor in C#

Tags: c#

I am attempting to count the characters in a text area using the cursor in C#. For example, I have a string of characters in the text area: "Please count my characters". If I highlight " characters", it should tell me that it has 11 characters including the whitespace.

Thanks who viewed and answered my inquiry.

Comment: Are you using Win Forms? WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        label1.Text = richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length.ToString();
}
```

**EDIT:**

for textboxes use this but I will prefer using richTextbox

```
textBox1.SelectionLength.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

In Winforms, just call `textbox.SelectedText.Length`.  Same goes for WPF

Comment: textboxes in winforms never had SelectedText event (Dunno about WPF). richTextBoxes have that property

Comment: @Ankush I just checked the docs for Textbox back to .Net 1.1 - they all have the SelectedText property

Comment: @gibz357 If your using WPF, there is a SelectionChanged event. I am currently searching for such an event in WinForms. Looks like it might only be supported by RichTextBox

Comment: we can have the length of selected text in textbox from this code for sure :_ textBox1.SelectionLength.ToString();              but I donot know what event to fire for catching this. as I cannot find SelectionChanged for textboxes in winforms

Comment: Definitely use RichTextBox in WinForms - any possible solution using a regular TextBox would just be overly ugly.